# Get all retweets of a certain tweet with Twitter4J

Tags: java, twitter4j

As the title suggests, I'm trying to get all the retweets of a certain tweet.

I'm aware of [getRetweets](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TweetsResources.html#getRetweets%28long%29) but it returns only 100 of the first retweets.

I'm not even sure this is possible without some elevated perms since this limitation appears to be there to prevent overloading, but if it I'd be happy for some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation of the Twitter API, not twitter4j

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweets/:id

Comment: Damn I was hoping this wasn't the case. Thanks.

Comment: API version1 is deprecated FYI. Plz check with Version1.1